# TabLayout+ViewPager+Fragment the first tab didn't display the data?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

I use TabLayout+ViewPager+Fragment in my Activity,when I enter the Activity,the first fragment didn't display the data,but I scrolled to the second fragment then scrolled to the third fragment,and I scrolled to the first fragment again,the first fragment display the data. I didn't know why this is.And I try to changed`FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`,it didn't work. The following is my code:

```
titles = new ArrayList<>();
 titles.add("未使用");
 titles.add("已使用");
 titles.add("已失效");
 fragments = new ArrayList<>();
 fragments.add(new TicketUnuseFragment());
 fragments.add(new TicketUseFragment());
 fragments.add(new TicketInvalidFragment());

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.award_tablayout);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.award_view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

}
```

The TicketUnuseFragment code:

```
ublic class TicketUnuseFragment extends AbsFragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AwardCenterRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter;

@Override
public void onServerMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.obj != null) {
        IResponseVO iResponseVO = (IResponseVO) msg.obj;
        if (iResponseVO.getServerCode().equals(ServerCode.PatientCouponList)) {
            if (HttpClient.RESULT_OK == iResponseVO.getStatus()) {
                AwardCenterListResponse mpRespBean = (AwardCenterListResponse) iResponseVO;
                recyclerAdapter.setData(mpRespBean.getList());
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected View initViews(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket_unused, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.unuse_ticket_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity));
    recyclerAdapter = new AwardCenterRecyclerViewAdapter(mActivity);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    return view;
}


@Override
protected void initVariables() {
}

@Override
protected void loadData() {
    try {
        RwardCenterRequest requestBean = new RwardCenterRequest();
        requestBean.setTabType(1);
        requestBean.setPage(0);
        HttpClient.getInstance(mActivity).requestTextByPost(mActivity, requestHandler, ServerCode.PatientCouponList, requestBean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

[image]

[image]
Thanks, advanced!

Comment: try to add viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); may be help

Comment: also share layout.xml

Comment: @ Mitesh Vanaliya it didn't work

Comment: Any error in logcat ?

Comment: i am having same problem did you get it solved @Jsonzsl

Answer (score 0):

Population of the tabs to display is done through TabLayout.Tab instances.
So in your main code just after getting the reference of the TabLayout add these lines.

```
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("未使用""));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("已使用"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("已失效"));
```

Comment: In  onCreateView() of your TicketsUnuseFragment's add a Log statement,this way you can check that whether the error is with ViewPager or with TicketsUnuseFragment.